# Perform a connected-check every n seconds on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsthread

I am currently writing an app for the iOS platform which communicates to a server through TCP. The problem is: I want to start an `NSThread` which runs into an infinite loop that checks that my

```
- (BOOL)connected
```

still returns true every 10 seconds, once the connect function has returned successful.

How can I make a timer that runs a function and checks its return value every 10 seconds?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do not you use `NSTimer` to run a timer which will run every 10 seconds to check the status of connection?

`NSTimer` reference is given [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/timerWithTimeInterval%3ainvocation%3arepeats%3a). There are many static methods to create a timer. You can use for example:

```
+ (NSTimer *)timerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

You can use it as

```
NSTimer * timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:10 target:myobject selector:checkConnectionStatus userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

where `myobject` will be an Objective-C object and its method `-checkConnectionStatus` or which method you like will check the status of the connection.

Comment: Good answer @doptimusprime
but needs This line of code to make your code runnable 
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout the Reachability sample code from Apple. I don't know much about TCP, but what you are describing sounds like it is going to burn through the battery quickly. Unless TCP works without waking the radios off course.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will have a look at it!